# <select> selection not showing on Windows computers

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Website in question: http://allaboutfreight.co.uk/samedaycourier.php

On this page there is a form where the user inputs the collection location and delivery location, a date and then picks a time from a drop down list.

When the user selects a time on any device apart from an OSX computer, the selection does not show in the box. The time HAS been selected but the user can't tell if it has.

```
<select name="time" id="time" class="form-control">
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    ...                 
    <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
</select>
```

I have checked the css and disabled each style individually but it still does not show.

Comment: I have a windows machine and I can see the select dropdown just fine

Comment: Is this an issue with any specific browser, an OS really would affect your page styles to this extent..have you tested with more than one browser in windows?

Comment: @Andrew I just checked this myself, it's not about the dropdown not showing but that whatever you click doesn't show up in the box. It'll stay blank. (The selection itself DOES work, it just doesn't show well.) I tested this with `$('#time').val()` and it returned `6:30` which is what I clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input field is to small, try following and you will see what I mean:

```
.form-control {
    height: 60px;
}
```

I think 70px is enough to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you go through your bootstrap css you will find that `form-control` class is having `padding: 25px 19px;` just change 25px to less than 6px you issue will get solved
And as well you will see the placeholders for your other fields

1. To (Postcode)
2. From (Postcode)
3. dd/mm/yyyy.

OR

You can override the `padding` property and set this to zero